# jquery $(".class").append(var1,var2,var3,etc): some work but some don't

Tags: jquery, append, html-select

So first of all, I am trying to make a gpa calculator, and this is my javascript:

```
<script>
var option_choose = document.createElement("option");
    option_choose.innerHTML = "Choose...";
    option_choose.value = -1;
var c1 = document.createElement("option");
    c1.innerHTML = "Math Standard 9"
    c1.value = 0;
var c2 = document.createElement("option");
    c2.innerHTML = "Math Higher 9"
    c2.value = 0.5; 
var c3 = document.createElement("option");
    c3.innerHTML = "English 9"
    c3.value = 0;
var c4 = document.createElement("option");
    c4.innerHTML = "History 9"
    c4.value = 0;
var c5 = document.createElement("option");
    c5.innerHTML = "Science 9";
    c5.value = 0;

var l1 = document.createElement("option");
    l1.innerHTML = "Japanese";
    l1.value = 0;
var l2 = document.createElement("option");
    l2.innerHTML = "French";
    l2.value = 0;

var e1 = document.createElement("option");
    e1.innerHTML = "Adv. Computers";
    e1.value = 0;

$(".core_subjects").append(option_choose,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);
$(".language_subjects").append(option_choose,l1,l2);
$(".elective_subjects").append(option_choose,e1);
</script>
```

and in my HTML, i have:

```
<div id="subject_name">
<h4>Class</h4>
<select id="core1" class="core_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="core2" class="core_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="core3" class="core_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="core4" class="core_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="language" class="language_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="elective1" class="elective_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="elective2" class="elective_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="elective3" class="elective_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
<select id="elective4" class="elective_subjects">
    <option value="-1">Choose...</option>
</select>
<br/>
</div>
```

So basically, when somebody clicks a button, the javascript will run, and in each select, there's supposed to be a "Choose..." option first followed by a list of classes.

But for some reason, in the two selects with #core4 and #language, the "Choose..." doesn't appear. It appears on all the others.

Answer (score 0):

You had `option_choose` when it should be `option_choose_c`. This error was clear in the error console.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bUh9E/

```
$(".core_subjects").append(option_choose_c,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5);
$(".language_subjects").append(option_choose_c,l1,l2);
$(".elective_subjects").append(option_choose_c,e1);
```

Comment: oh sorry. the variable declaration is also option_choose, not option_choose_c